# Debugging driver locally

Tags: windows, debugging, driver

Is there anyway I can test/debug Window drivers locally? That way I don't need a separate computer or to install a VM.

I followed these instructions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553382(v=vs.85).aspx

But I can't get past the welcome screen with `bcdedit /debug on` enabled. My computer just hangs there.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and the Windows 8.1 Driver Kit

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, local kernel debugging is next to worthless.

Even if it wasn't worthless, targeting a separate machine (virtual or physical) is the way to go, as kernel mode drivers under development can (and most likely *will*) destabilize the target machine until they're complete - something that you likely don't want happening on your development machine.

Comment: Okay, I'll download VMware. 
But in the meantime, how would I test my driver? Is there a software I can use?

Comment: Windows device drivers are essentially extensions of the operating system (think of them as DLLs loaded into the Windows Kernel "process").  In order to test/debug such a component, you'll need an instance of Windows that you wouldn't mind crashing.  A separate virtual or physical machine running Windows is really the only way to accomplish this.